# Consolidating PHP files so I don't have to call include a dozen times

Tags: php, performance, file, include, concatenation

Considering computers now have tons of memory, I think that by combining my include files into just one file will make things run faster in the long run. The problem is when I combine them and then I try to execute my code in a web browser, I get nothing on screen, however when I try to execute it on the command line it does give me warnings about server variables not being set which is normal but the expected output (of an HTML page) does not appear.

Some of the files have includes and requires to other files in the same folder and I'm not sure if that is part of the problem, but php is telling me nothing. Is there a special way to consolidate all files into one so I don't have to make a dozen calls to include?

```
    <?php
      $DIR=getcwd();
      $alldeps=array(
        "./file1.php",
        "./afile.php",
        "./somefile.php",
        "./somenewfile.php",
        "./filexxxx.php",
        "./file1file2.php"
        );

      $dat=filesize($DIR.'./includeall.php');
      if ($dat < 2){
        $h=fopen($DIR.'./includeall.php','w+');
        $depct=count($alldeps);
        for($i=0;$i<$depct;$i++){
          fwrite($h,file_get_contents($DIR.$alldeps[$i]));
        }
        fclose($h);
      }
      include './includeall.php';
      //rest of root php code (not requiring include) here.
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're getting a blank page in the browser, you're probably getting an error. What do your server logs say? Also, you probably shouldn't worry about the performance impact of include, especially if you're using APC or opcache, unless you're on a monstrously huge site.

Comment: The php error log does not give any additional information than what I saw.

Comment: is display_errors=1 and error_reporting=E_ALL in your php.ini?

Comment: How big is your site? Run `php -l includeall.php` from the command line to do a lint test on your file... honestly pretty skeptical that this will greatly improve the speed of your site.  Seems like micro-optimization or pre-mature optimization.  Is this really a bottleneck for your site?